# How do I combine multiple SQS metrics with Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lambda

I have SQS monitoring for some services we have. We have two metrics that I'm looking to combine. "Receives" and "Empty Receives".

Is it possible to use something like amazon lambda to create an aggregate metric of those two queues? If so, what documentation in Lambda should I be looking at to do so?

Comment: You can use available AWS SDK, e.g. boto3 for python, get CloudWatch metrics from the queue you want, aggregate them and then publish your new custom metric back (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/cw-example-metrics.html).